# How to get non standard tags in rpm query

Tags: linux, rpm

I wanted to add things such as Size, BuildHost, BuildDate etc in rpm query but adding this thing in spec file results in unknown tag?? How can I do this so that these things are reflected when i give the rpm query command?

Answer (score 2):

These tags are determined when the package is built; they cannot be forced to specific values.

Comment: If these tags are not present in spec files then will it be shown in rpm query??

Comment: Yes, since they are part of the specification regardless.

Comment: If i have to know about how these tags are propagated which are not in spec files then where should i look at??

Comment: rpm -v --querytag will display information about tag names/types. note that the -v must precede --querytags to see compete information because querytags is executed immediately while processing CLI options and the -v will not be seen.

Answer (score 1):

For example BuildHost is hardcoded in rpmbuild and cannot be changed. There is RFE https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1309367 to allow it modify from command line. But right now you cannot change it by any tag in spec file nor by passing some option on command line to rpmbuild.

I assume it will be very similar to other values you specified.

Comment: It is possible to change the build host. I've been doing it for years. [Here's how](http://www.revragnarok.com/blog/blog/rpm_spoof_hostname).

Comment: Replacing gethostname is one way to spoof the hostname, Meanwhile, you can likely achieve the same effect using /etc/hosts and /etc/nsswitch.conf in a chroot or within the VM used to build. RPM tries to use the FQDN, add other host names as aliases as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

RPM5 permits arbitrary unique tag names to be added to header metadata.

The tag names are configured in a colon separated list in a macro. Then the new tags can be used in spec files and can be extracted using --queryformat.

All arbitrary tags are string (or string array) valued.

Comment: @Jeff..can you please tell me more about it or share any documentation regarding that.?? I am trying to add "buildpath" tag.. so what should be added to the macro file ??

Comment: Arbitrary tags are supported by rpm5.org, not the usual Red Hat rpm.org, code. Feel free to ask any questions you wish at <rpm-devel@rpm5.org> regarding arbitrary tags (and the archives likely have some answers when implemented ~2008 iirc).

Comment: can you tell me how to configure the extra tag which is "buildpath" in my case in the macro list and is there any extra changes which we have to do in the source file ?

Comment: rpm -qp --xml *.rpm will show all the metadata in a package. (rpm5 also has --yaml, which is easier to read).

Comment: rpm5 appears dead. Sadly, because rpm.org really needs some love to help with things like this. Custom tags, yaml or json output for metadata etc.